# rsync --delete with superset destination folder

Tags: rsync

I have an `rsync` process which is syncing content from a source repository (which is version controlled) into a shared NFS mount.

The scenario (as awful as it is) is that the destination folder contains more content than the source folder because other content is synced to the destination folder from different sources. So for instance, folder structures may look like this:

**source**

```
a/a1.txt
a/a2.txt
b/b1.txt
```

**destination**

```
a/a1.txt
a/a2.txt
a/a3.txt
b/b1.txt
c/c1.txt
```

(in this example, `a/a3.txt` and `c/c1.txt` are synced to the destination from elsewhere. In practice this involves multiple other sources and the content/processes for these can’t be influenced.)

Now say that source folder deletes the `a/a2.txt` file. Using the existing setup, this file would not be deleted on the destination; but using `--delete` would result in other files being deleted, and it is a requirement to not do this.

How could `--delete` be used on this rsync but meet the requirement? Because the source directory is version controlled, it is simple enough to get a before-and-after of this directory, so a differential backup could be calculated using the original source directory as a reference, but is this the best way?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `rsync --delete` like this. It's stateless and keeps no record of which files have been deleted between runs. The `--delete` flag simply instructs `rsync` to delete every file on the destination that does not exist on the source.

In order to implement this constrained deletion I think you need to maintain your own state. Neither `rsync` nor `unison` can do this for you.

The following is not a full error-safe solution; it's a starting point. (However, it does handle files with strange names - including those containing an embedded newline.)

Assume two directories `src` and `dst`. (For the purposes of the example it doesn't really matter whether `dst` is local or remote.)

```
# Find the current list of files (do this just once, to prep the cache)
( cd src && find . -type f -print0 ) | LC_ALL=C sort -z > .state.src
```

Each time we perform a backup, run the following code

```
# Run the rsync to transfer files. "dst/" could be local
rsync -av src/ remote:dst/

# Determine the set of files to delete in "dst/"
( cd src && find . -type f -print0 ) | LC_ALL=C sort -z | tee .state.src.new |
    LC_ALL=C comm -z - -13 .state.src |
    ssh remote 'while IFS= read -d "" -r f; do rm -f "dst/$f"; done'

# That seemed to work, so update the state cache
[[ 0 -eq $? ]] && mv -f .state.src.new .state.src
```

---

If your version of `comm` (like mine) is older than GNU coreutils 8.25 and does not have the `-z` flag, you can use this alternative workaround:

```
# Find the current list of files (do this just once, to prep the cache)
( cd src && find . -type f -print0 ) | tr '\0\n' '\n\0' | LC_ALL=C sort > .state.src
```

Each time we perform a backup, run the following code

```
# Run the rsync to transfer files. "dst/" could be local
rsync -av src/ remote:dst/

# Determine the set of files to delete in "dst/"
( cd src && find . -type f  -print0 ) | tr '\0\n' '\n\0' | LC_ALL=C sort | tee .state.src.new |
    LC_ALL=C comm -13 - .state.src |
    tr '\0\n' '\n\0' |
    ssh remote 'while IFS= read -d "" -r f; do rm -f "dst/$f"; done'

# That seemed to work, so update the state cache
[[ 0 -eq $? ]] && mv -f .state.src.new .state.src
```

Comment: I'm aware of this, but if I have my source directory under version control, then I have the state I need, it's just a question of whether `--compare-dest` could be used for this at all.

Comment: @cmbuckley try the new code I've added to the answer

Comment: Reference [Using comm with NULL-terminated records](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/446939/100397)

Comment: @cmbuckley `--compare-dest` does not affect `--delete` so that won't do what you want either. You will need the "before" state of the source, no way around that. If your version control tool can generate a commit diff for the entire directory just make one of those and apply the diff to the destination.

Comment: @jw013 that sounds like a sufficiently different answer that you could reasonably make it one

Comment: Right, `diff` it is!

Comment: It looks like a good solution, but I haven't had time to have a play with this yet. Given that I have a VCS at the source, I'll also try using diff tools to generate the state files. I just needed the confirmation above that I couldn't manage this with rsync alone.