# Using comm with NULL-terminated records

Tags: find, sort, comm

Over in [an answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/446878/100397) to a different question, I wanted to use a structure much like this to find files that appear in `list2` that do not appear in `list1`:

```
( cd dir1 && find . -type f -print0 ) | sort -z > list1
( cd dir2 && find . -type f -print0 ) | sort -z > list2
comm -13 list1 list2
```

However, I hit a brick wall because my version of `comm` cannot handle NULL-terminated records. (Some background: I'm passing a computed list to `rm`, so I particularly want to be able to handle file names that could contain an embedded newline.)

If you want an easy worked example, try this

```
mkdir dir1 dir2
touch dir1/{a,b,c} dir2/{a,c,d}
( cd dir1 && find . -type f ) | sort > list1
( cd dir2 && find . -type f ) | sort > list2
comm -13 list1 list2
```

Without NULL-terminated lines the output here is the single element `./d` that appears only in `list2`.

I'd like to be able to use `find ... -print0 | sort -z` to generate the lists.

How can I best reimplement an equivalent to `comm` that outputs the NULL-terminated records that appear in `list2` but that do not appear in `list1`?

Comment: Do you really have filenames with NEW-lines inside?

Comment: @schily it's not difficult to create them, and seeing as I'm passing a computed list to `rm` I'd like to be sure and code defensively. I'll clarify in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU `comm` (as of GNU coreutils 8.25) now has a `-z`/`--zero-terminated` option for that.

For older versions of GNU `comm`, you should be able to swap NUL and NL:

```
comm -13 <(cd dir1 && find . -type f -print0 | tr '\n\0' '\0\n' | sort) \
         <(cd dir2 && find . -type f -print0 | tr '\n\0' '\0\n' | sort) |
  tr '\n\0' '\0\n'
```

That way `comm` still works with newline-delimited records, but with actual newlines in the input encoded as NULs, so we're still safe with filenames containing newlines.

You may also want to set the locale to `C` because on GNU systems and most UTF-8 locales at least, there are different strings that sort the same and would cause problems here¹.

That's a very common trick (see [Invert matching lines, NUL-separated](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/251154) for another example with `comm`), but needs utilities that support NUL in their input, which outside of GNU systems is relatively rare.

---

¹ Example:

```
$ touch dir1/{①,②} dir2/{②,③}
$ comm -12 <(cd dir1 && find . -type f -print0 | tr '\n\0' '\0\n' | sort) \
           <(cd dir2 && find . -type f -print0 | tr '\n\0' '\0\n' | sort)  
./③
./②
$ (export LC_ALL=C
    comm -12 <(cd dir1 && find . -type f -print0 | tr '\n\0' '\0\n' | sort) \
             <(cd dir2 && find . -type f -print0 | tr '\n\0' '\0\n' | sort))
./②
```

(**2019 edit**: The relative order of ①②③ has been fixed in newer versions of the GNU libc, but you can use    instead for instance in newer versions (2.30 at least) that still have the problem like 95% of Unicode code points)

Comment: What problems would cause *strings that sort the same* ? Examples?

Comment: @issac, see edit. There's also a related discussion around 2015-03-30 on the austin group mailing list (you can use the gmane NNTP interface) you may be interested in reading on the subject.